# Unable to access ajax data from servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am trying to access the JSON Data sent from client in Java Servlet. I am unable to see the data.

**My client Code:**

```
// userObj - the user object 

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '/myServlet',
    success : function(result) {alert(result)},
    data : JSON.stringify(userObj),
});
```

**At server side:**

I am trying to read `request.getParameterMap(),` but I am unable to see the data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `JSON` parser to parse the Servlet data if your AJAX requests sends the data properly.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameter(<request_parameter_name>)); 
Iterator it = jObj.keys(); 
while(it.hasNext()) {
    //Key
    String key = it.next(); 
    //Value.
    Object value = jObj.get(key); 

}
```

This [page](http://www.json.org/) lists all JSON parsers language-wise